# My python code is not executing a function (program) I coded

Tags: python

I created a program that asks a bunch of input questions and prints out the following line, for example, Marc Gibbons is a 103 year old male. He was born in Ottawa and his SIN # is 1234567890.

But when I keep getting an error.

[image]

```
from datetime import datetime

def main():
name = input('Please enter your name:')

sex = input('Please enter your sex, Male (M) or Female (F) or Non-Binanry(N):')

birthday = input ('Enter your date of birth in YYYY-mm-dd format:')

birthday1 = datetime.strptime(birthday, '%Y-%m-%d')
age =  ((datetime.today() - birthday1).days/365)

place = input('What City were you born in:')

    try:
        sin = int(input('What is your sin number:'))
    except ValueError:
        print('Error:Please enter a number')

print(f'{name} is a {age} years old {sex}. He was born in {place} and her SIN # is {sin}')

# Do not edit below
if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: Maybe you want the print statement indented in the `main()` function?

Comment: move `print(f"...")` after `sin = ...`

Comment: That worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

just make sure that `print(f'{name} is a {age} years old {sex}. He was born in {place} and her SIN # is {sin}')` indented right inside the function

Comment: How do I incorporate  he/she in my sentence based on the answer provided by the input, female or male?

Comment: you can add `pronoun = 'he' if sex=='m' else 'she'` and edit `print(f'{name} is a {age} years old {sex}. {pronoun} was born in {place} and her SIN # is {sin}')`

Answer (score 1):

move the print state into the function. The current indentation means `main()` (containing your `name` var) is not in the same scope as the print function:

```
from datetime import datetime

def main():
    name = input('Please enter your name:')

    sex = input('Please enter your sex, Male (M) or Female (F) or Non-Binanry(N):')

    birthday = input ('Enter your date of birth in YYYY-mm-dd format:')

    birthday1 = datetime.strptime(birthday, '%Y-%m-%d')
    age =  ((datetime.today() - birthday1).days/365)

    place = input('What City were you born in:')

    try:
        sin = int(input('What is your sin number:'))
    except ValueError:
        print('Error:Please enter a number')

    # Indent here to inside the function
    print(f'{name} is a {age} years old {sex}. He was born in {place} and her SIN # is {sin}')
```

Hope it helps